# Retrieving EXIF from image

Tags: javascript, image, exif

I am using this library http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/reading-exif-data-with-javascript.html. I'm calling the library like this: `EXIF.pretty(image)` where the image is an image object. My result is an empty string even if I use an image with EXIF data. What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried this way:

```
var binary_reader = new FileReader();

     var temp = binary_reader.readAsBinaryString(image);
     var temp2 = new BinaryFile(temp);

    alert(EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(temp2));
```

But no succes. Please help!

Comment: Are you including the exif.js file in the page as well?

Answer (score 1):

`exif.readfrombinaryfile` does not return a single string or value. Try something like this to display a single EXIF value:

```
    var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(temp);
    alert(exif.Make);
```

Comment: I get an error: Object HTMLImageElement has no method 'getByteAt'